# how do I replace spaces with the string "\|" using sed?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to set up an exclusion list to pass to "grep -v" via a shell var, made up of mount points with the initial "/" removed and all separated by spaces. I'm building it like this:

```
EXCLUDE_LIST=$(mount | grep -v '/dev/' | awk '{ print $3 }' | sed 's,^[^/]*/,,' )
```

This yields the string 'dev proc sys tmp var/run'. This is the string I want to replace spaces with the '\|' so "grep -v" can use it.

Ive tried appending

```
sed 's/ /\|/g'
```

to the previous pipeline, then

```
sed 's/ /\\|/g'
```

and

```
sed 's/ /\\\|/g'
```

What I want is "dev\|proc\|sys\|tmp\|var/run", but I'm always getting "dev proc sys tmp var/run".

**EDIT**

The output of mount is

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,reltime,nobarrier,commit=10)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,sync,size=1024k,nr_inodes=502793,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime,sync,size=1024k)
procfs on /proc type procfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime,sync,size=524288k)
tmpfs on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,relatime,sync,size=131072k)
```

The output of "mount | grep -v '/dev/'" is:

```
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,sync,size=1024k,nr_inodes=502793,mode=755)
procfs on /proc type procfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime,sync,size=524288k)
tmpfs on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,relatime,sync,size=131072k)
```

The output of "mount | grep -v '/dev/' | awk { print $3 }" is:

```
/dev
/proc
/sys
/tmp
/var/run
```

And finally, the output of "mount | grep -v '/dev/' | awk { print $3 } | sed 's,^[^/]*/,,'" is

```
dev proc sys tmp var/run
```

as previously stated.

Comment: Add output of `mount` and your desired output for that to your question.

Comment: `echo 'dev proc sys tmp var/run'|sed 's/ /\|/g'` actually yields `dev|proc|sys|tmp|var/run`, what's your `sed`'s version?

Comment: Cyrus, added the outputs of the various stages of the pipeline. I don't understand your second request, that's there at the end.

Comment: Tiw. Yes, and I just tried echo "dev proc" | sed 's/ /\\\|/g' and I get "dev\|proc" as I'd like. But if I do echo $EXCLUDE_LIST, as I'm doing now in my script, nothing.

And it's GNU sed 4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single `awk` command:

```
mount | awk '!/\/dev\//{sub("/",d,$3);print $3;d="\\|"}' ORS=''
```

With the given input of `mount` it will print

```
dev\|proc\|sys\|tmp\|var/run
```

Explanation:

```
# Applies to all lines with does not match /dev
!/\/dev/{
    # Remove leading / with delimiter d
    # d will be empty upon first use
    sub("/","",$3)
    # Print the column
    print $3
    # Set delimiter after first usage
    d="\\|"
}
```

`ORS=''` will silence awk's output record delimiter.

Comment: Close, but no cigar! Its output is proc\|sys\|tmp\|var/run. It's eating up the initial "dev", which I need.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Changed

Comment: This command works perfectly, thanx! One thing tough, it's printing out a warniing: "awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\|' treated as plain `|'". Any idea on how to get rid of that?

Comment: Use `\\\|` as I have shown. Or just copy the command _as is_ from my answer. Doesn't that work?

Comment: I DID use `\\\|`. I can't actually copy&paste as I'm running that command on a VM with a custom LFS system (i.e. no shared clipboard :-()

Comment: I don't know from where you are running this. There must be one additional layer of double quoting in between. I bet the invocation of the `grep` command. Instead of finding that out I would recommend to use `|` instead of `\|` and then `grep -E ...`. You don't need to escape the `|` when you run `grep -E`. Just use `d="|"` then

Comment: Grep? I ran that command as is and I get that warning. That is BEFORE I pass it to grep.

Comment: You say you typed my command as is? You did not mix single with double quotes at some point? Because that would explain what you see. Note that every quote is by intention

Comment: OK, I tried `\\|` instead of `\\\|`. Warning's gone. Thank you.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry, that was my fault!!! Of course it must be two \. Sorry doing some other work in the meanwhile...

Comment: @Tiw it depends on the type of quotes you use in the shell: `ORS='\\|'` or `ORS="\\\|"`. That's because the shell will expand double quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try append this:

```
awk -v RS="" '{gsub(/[\r\n]+/,"\\|")}1'
```

That is:

```
mount | grep -v '/dev/' | awk '{ print $3 }' | sed 's,^[^/]*/,,' | awk -v RS="" '{gsub(/[\r\n]+/,"\\|")}1'
#=> sys\|proc\|dev\|sys/kernel/security\|run\|sys/fs/cgroup\|sys/fs/cgroup/systemd\|...
```

Btw, what system are you in? -- Seems it treats mount's output `\n` newlines as spaces.
-- Or is it just your typing error?

Since normally your series of commands will yield:

```
sys
proc
dev
sys/kernel/security
run
...
```

But you said it's a spaces separated string, so my best guess is your system/editor shows `\n` as space, which misled you believe they are spaces.
Correct me if I guess wrong.

Made a mistake, just fixed.
Also I don't believe `sed` will just change line-endings to spaces by itself...

Well, for fun, tried `awk` way too:

```
mount | awk -v ORS="\\\|" '$0!~"/dev/"{print gensub("^/","",1,$3)}'
#=> sys\|proc\|dev\|sys/kernel/security\|run\|sys/fs/cgroup\|sys/fs/cgroup/systemd\|...
```

For fun again:

```
mount| awk '!(FNR%2) && !/dev\/|^$/' RS="on /| type " ORS="\\\|"
```

Both `awk` will leave trailing `\|`.

Comment: "Btw, what system are you in? -- Seems it treats mount's output \n newlines as spaces."Re-read the last element of the pipeline ;-)

Comment: Its GNU sed 4.5. Sorry, my bad. you're right. That's weird, It actually DOESN'T as you correctly pointed out. But when I run it from a script it does! Hmm...

Comment: Ah, assigning the output to a shell variable does that! So 'echo $EXCLUDE_LIST' shows spaces in place of the '\n's

Comment: Do not chain many `sed`, `grep`, `awk` commands together. Use `awk` effeciently

Comment: The problem with the single `awk` command is that it will print a trailing `\|`

Comment: @hek2mgl That trailing '\|' is actually what I need ;-)

Comment: That would mean _or empty_ how does that make sense? I mean your grep would match everything, like this `grep 'a\|b\|' <<< 'foo'` output `foo`

Comment: @Tiw Yes, yes I do. It's very handy to have, as the variable is concatenated with another string ;-)

Comment: What stops you from concatenating it with `\|OTHER_STRING`.  How is that less handy?